# Как забрать количество товаров, просмотренные пользователем?

Tags: php, битрикс

Необходимо забрать количество(цифру) просмотренных товаров, не могу разобраться где ее взять или посчитать. Включен компонент catalog.products.viewed. Сама страница работает, необходимо на любой странице сайта иметь цифру количества просмотренных товаров.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью класса [`CatalogViewedProductTable`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/catalog/catalogviewedproducttable/index.php) (о чем можно узнать с помощью написания запроса в [гугл](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=bitrix%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5).

Вот пример как им можно воспользоваться:

```
$arViewed = array();
$basketUserId = (int)CSaleBasket::GetBasketUserID(true);
if ($basketUserId > 0){
   $viewedIterator = \Bitrix\Catalog\CatalogViewedProductTable::getList(array(
      'select' => array('PRODUCT_ID', 'ELEMENT_ID'),
      'filter' => array('=FUSER_ID' => $basketUserId, '=SITE_ID' => SITE_ID),
      'order' => array('DATE_VISIT' => 'DESC'),
      'limit' => 10
   ));

   while ($arFields = $viewedIterator->fetch()){
      $arViewed[] = $arFields['ELEMENT_ID'];
   }
}
echo count($arViewed);
```

Этот код можно использовать на лююбой странице сайта для подсчета количества просмотренных элементов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, можно и так, но нашел решение проще.
$var=\Bitrix\Catalog\CatalogViewedProductTable::getList(['filter' => ['FUSER_ID' => \Bitrix\Sale\Fuser::getId()]])->getSelectedRowsCount();

Comment: @alexnn09 не забудьте про волшебную переменную `$skipCreate` в методе `\Bitrix\Sale\Fuser::getId()`, если она работает по аналогии с `bSkipFUserInit` из `CSaleBasket::GetBasketUserID`, то по-умолчанию она false и у вас для неавторизованного пользователя создается запись в таблице `b_sale_fuser`, что может быть иногда вредно. Поскольку я не нашел нюансов работы `\Bitrix\Sale\Fuser::getId()`, то не стал его приводит, а так да. вариант d7 вполне имеет место быть.

Comment: параметр `'select'` лучше задавать чтобы ограничивать объем выбираемых данных для скорости работы запроса.